# How to activate speech recognition?

Tags: 8.0, apps, speech

Is/will the speech recognition be available on Windows Phone 8? And by speech recognition I mean converting speech to text eg. email/sms/message on any messaging app. Or maybe I missed it somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can speek to text by going into the messaging app, prepare to start a message, and tapping the microphone on the application bar at the bottom of the screen. It will then allow you to dictate text in.

The same icon is also used in the default email app.

Comment: Important thing is that it won't work offline.

Comment: Correct, without access to cellular internet connect, or wifi, this way of using speech will not work.

Comment: Yes, I saw it when I tried to send text without network connection.

Answer (score 2):

Pressing and holding the Windows/Start key, and it will start up the voice commands, which can do things like "**Call** Chris mobile" or "**Find** coffee in London" or "**Open** calendar" or "**Text** Amy" or even "**Note** send birthday card".

Some other apps, such as messaging and email, also have a microphone icon in the application bar for dictation.